# Only the last record in sql table is being updated from a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, forms

I have implemented LIKE functionality but only the last record in the table gets the update, regardless of which row's LIKE button the user clicks.

I have looked other questions similar to this here and elsewhere and have tried the suggested remedies but nothing works. Any help appreciated!

This outputs the table, with a column for a LIKE button:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
           <tr>
            <th>Word ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Meaning</th>
            <th>Example</th>
            <th>Likes</th>
                   </tr>';

    foreach ($data as $row) 
      { 
        echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row as $value)
                  { 
                echo '<td>';
                    echo $value;
                echo '</td>';
              } 
echo '<td>
 <form method="POST" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">
<input type="hidden" name="LIKE" value="'.$row['wordID'].'">
<input id="'.$row['wordID'].'" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="LIKE">
</form> 

     </td>';      
            echo '</tr>';
          }

        echo '</table>';
```

My update code is:

```
if($_POST['submit'])  
 {
$sql = "UPDATE vocab SET likes = likes+1 where wordID = '{$row['wordID']}'"; 

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

I've tried everything including adding a javascript such as this to get the required ID to the update code. No luck!

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm(){

                var selectButton = document.getElementById( "'.$row['wordID'].'" );
                selectButton.click();
        }
</script>';
```

Comment: Where is that Javascript code?

Comment: It's straight after the first snippet above - just after the table is echoed out.

Comment: That's your problem. At the end of the loop, `$row['wordID']` is still what it was at the end of the loop (your last value).

Comment: In my own experience, when only the "last" one of something is being updated, it means that my HTML has duplicated information. Have you inspected your HTML in the browser to make sure that each form and _LIKE_ button has the expected id and value?

Comment: Yes, @kchason and Aj, I did an echo to test, and it outputs worIDs to screen as 123456 (if there's six rows) so the last value is what the update code is getting. But how do I get it to take the *selected* wordID value?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to pass that to the server side. A button or link that does it asynchronously on each row. Something where that function gets the correct ID from the calling object, or a URL request, depending on how your system is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
I would change:

```
<input name="like" value="'.$row['wordID'].'" 
    type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
```

And also:

```
if (!empty($_POST['like'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE vocab SET likes = likes+1 where wordID = '".$_POST['like']."'"; 

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    ...
```

**Option 2:**
To show like as the button value try this:

```
<input name="like['.$row['wordID'].']" value="LIKE" 
    type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
```

and in the php file:

```
if (!empty($_POST['like'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['like'] as $key => $value) {
        $sql = "UPDATE vocab SET likes = likes+1 where wordID = '".$key."'"; 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
<input name="like_'.$row['wordID'].'" value="LIKE" 
    type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
```

and:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'like_') {
            $sql = "UPDATE vocab SET likes = likes+1 where wordID = '".substr($key, 5)."'"; 

            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            ...
```

But be carefull with SQL injection. You should sanitise the $_POST['like'] value before performing the query or execute prepared queries with parameters.

Comment: YES! You beauty! Thanks, jeprubio.

Comment: Just one thing @jeprubio , the form button now bear the numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. because the value attribute takes the wordID. How can I make the buttons all  show LIKE, as the user will expect?

Comment: I've just added an update. The idea is sending the id in the key as an array, this way you can walk through the array keys to get the ids. I have not tested it but should work.

Comment: Thanks, I ran it and am getting syntax error, unexpected 'wordID' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I tried <input name="like'.[$row['wordID']].'" value="LIKE"  and got it error free using online interpreter (sandbox) but it breaks on my own server!

Comment: I was editing the answer, try this 2 last options. One is using an array as the key and the other one is using a string with a token as the prefix.

Comment: I tried the string and token but it breaks also: unexpected end of file  :(

Comment: Check that all the ifs and foreach are closed before the script finishes

Comment: YESSS! You are absolutely brilliant! Thanks so much jeprubio. I had left out a curly.